# Angular view loading

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to load view using "$location.path"
Although my browser URLis getting updated but my content is not getting loaded. Here is the controller code:

```
var app= angular.module("LoginModule",[]);
app.controller("LoginController",['$scope','$http','$location',function($scope,$http,$location){
        $scope.submitForm= function(valid){
            if(valid){
               $http.get('/admin/dashboard').success(function(data){
                $location.path('dashboard');
                });
            }
        };
}]);
```

It is changing my URL to "http://example.com/admin#/dashboard" for the same page.
My router file code  is:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/admin', function(req, res) {
  res.render('admin/login', { title: 'Login' });
});


router.get('/admin/dashboard', function(req, res) {
    //res.render('admin/dashboard', { title: 'Welcome to dashboard' });
    res.send("success");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Please advise I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Why do you think changing the hashbang in the address bar would trigger a request to your server? Where is your **angular** routing configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the AngularJS docs at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location :

> Note: Path should always begin with forward slash (/), this method
>   will add the forward slash if it is missing.

so, you need to put the full value in there:

```
$location.path('/admin/dashboard');
```

instead of

```
$location.path('dashboard');
```

Comment: I tried it already but not working. I must be missing something.

Comment: when you do $location.path('/admin/dashboard') what is the resulting URL?

Comment: and, are you using ngRoute or ui-router? can you post that code?

Comment: I am working on an existing Express project. It is using Express router mechanism. Not sure about the ngrouter (Srry but I am new to angular js)

Comment: just want to confirm what you're expecting. you know that $location.path('whatever') is for AngularJS routing, right? It's not supposed to go back to the server from that at all. if you have a route/state defined in ngRoute or ui-router that matches "/admin/dashboard", that is what should be triggering client-side.

Comment: Routing mechanism for this request already added: router.get('/admin/dashboard', function(req, res) {
    //res.render('admin/dashboard', { title: 'Welcome to dashboard' });
    res.send("success");
});  I am able to get this page directly from browser request.

Comment: Great -- if my answer and comments were helpful, please upvote my answer and award an answer. thx!